# Uncaught TypeError when trying to create variable product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What does this Wordpress error mean:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Automattic\WooCommerce\Internal\ProductAttributesLookup\LookupDataStore::get_attribute_taxonomies(): Argument #1 ($product) must be of type WC_Product, bool given, called in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/src/Internal/ProductAttributesLookup/LookupDataStore.php on line 378 and defined in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/src/Internal/ProductAttributesLookup/LookupDataStore.php:516
```

I get the above error when I try to make a variable product in Woocommerce:

```
// Creating a variable product
$product = new WC_Product_Variable();

// Name and image would be enough
$product->set_name( 'Wizard Hat' );
$product->set_image_id( 90 );

// one available for variation attribute
$attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
$attribute->set_name( 'Magical' );
$attribute->set_options( array( 'Yes', 'No' ) );
$attribute->set_position( 0 );
$attribute->set_visible( true );
$attribute->set_variation( true ); // here it is
    
$product->set_attributes( array( $attribute ) );

// save the changes and go on
$product->save();

// now we need two variations for Magical and Non-magical Wizard hat
$variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
$variation->set_parent_id( $product->get_id() );
$variation->set_attributes( array( 'magical' => 'Yes' ) );
$variation->set_regular_price( 1000000 ); // yep, magic hat is quite expensive
$variation->save();

$variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
$variation->set_parent_id( $product->get_id() );
$variation->set_attributes( array( 'magical' => 'No' ) );
$variation->set_regular_price( 500 );
$variation->save();
```

P.S. The above code is an example. I am using this to create multiple products, whose informations are fetched from API and this code is in a loop in CRON.

Comment: The error is from somewhere in the WooCommerce internals, so it is not immediately evident, which line of your code above actually caused it. Can you try and reduce that example code, removing lines from the end one by one, until the error does not occur any more? That could help narrow it down a bit at least perhaps.